# having problem with drawing lines thickness in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Here is the board I drew using pygame: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hne6A.png

I'm facing a bug with the thickness of the last two lines as I marked them on the image. I believe there is something wrong with the if statement in my code but I can't quite figure it out, it just won't take effect.

here is the code that has drawn the board above:

```
import pygame, sys


pygame.init()

width, height = 750, 750
rows, cols = 9, 9
BLACK = (0,0,0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
screen.fill((255, 255, 255, 255))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            sys.exit()

    surf = pygame.Surface((600, 600))
    surf.fill((255,255,255))

    padding = surf.get_width()/9
    for i in range(rows+1):
        if i % 3 == 0:
            thick = 4
        else:
            thick = 1

        pygame.draw.line(surf, BLACK, (0, i*padding), (width, i*padding), width=thick)
        pygame.draw.line(surf, BLACK, (i*padding, 0), (i*padding, height), width=thick)

    

    surf_center = (
        (width-surf.get_width())/2,
        (height-surf.get_height())/2
    )
    screen.blit(surf, surf_center)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw a thick line, half the thickness is applied to both sides of the line. The simplest solution is to make the target surface a little larger and add a small offset to the coordinates of the lines.
For performance reasons, I also recommend creating the surface before the application loop and continuously `blit` it in the application loop:

```py
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()

width, height = 750, 750
rows, cols = 9, 9
BLACK = (0,0,0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

surf_size = 600
surf = pygame.Surface((surf_size+4, surf_size+4))
surf.fill((255,255,255))
padding = surf_size/9
for i in range(rows+1):
    thick = 4 if i % 3 == 0 else 1
    offset = i * padding + 1
    pygame.draw.line(surf, BLACK, (0, offset), (width, offset), width=thick)
    pygame.draw.line(surf, BLACK, (offset, 0), (offset, height), width=thick)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(surf, surf.get_rect(center = screen.get_rect().center))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

[image]

Comment: apparently, this code solved the bug but I don't understand this line again 'offset = i * padding + 1'

Comment: @arshiamohammadi In your original code it was `i*padding`, now it is `i*padding + 1` because the entire grid needs to be shifted slightly down right (by 1). This is because of the thickness of the left and top line.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should do the trick. The thing is that the `width` in `pygame.draw.line` is drawn in the middle of the line. So, the border lines are actually cropped in half because the half on one side and another half on the other side are not taken into account. But the catch is that if the thickness is even there is an offset of 1 on the borders as the width is larger on one of the sides.

Even if the thickness (`bold_think`) is raised or lowered the algorithm below will work flawlessly without any gaps outside the grid.

| Thickness of 4 | Thickness of 8 | Thinkness of 15 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Thickness of 4] | [image: Thickness of 8] | [image: Thickness of 15] |

```py
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

width, height = 750, 750
rows, cols = 9, 9
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
screen.fill((255, 255, 255, 255))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            sys.exit()

    surf = pygame.Surface((600, 600))
    surf.fill((255, 255, 255))

    bold_thick = 4
    # Calculates the offset of 1 for the even widths
    thick_offset = (bold_thick - 1) % 2
    offset = (bold_thick / 2) - thick_offset

    # The padding should take into account the borders
    padding = (surf.get_width() - bold_thick) / 9
    for i in range(rows+1):
        if i % 3 == 0:
            thick = bold_thick
        else:
            thick = 1

        pygame.draw.line(surf, BLACK, (0, i*padding + offset),
                         (width, i*padding + offset), width=thick)
        pygame.draw.line(surf, BLACK, (i*padding + offset, 0),
                         (i*padding + offset, height), width=thick)

    surf_center = (
        (width-surf.get_width())/2,
        (height-surf.get_height())/2
    )
    screen.blit(surf, surf_center)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
```